# Sidebar Navigation Menu on Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, sidebar

I've followed the TreeHouse tutorial on how to create a login/signup screen as well as the AppCoda tutorial for adding a sidebar navigation menu: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

I have the login/signup bar attached to my master viewcontroller which is hooked up to the sidebar viewcontroller. This makes for a funny bug where I can get to the main screen without logging in.

Can anyone suggest a storyboard layout where I can make the sidebar slideable only when I'm logged in?

[image: GIF of bug]

[image: My Storyboard layout]

Comment: I understand correctly, your RootViewController is MasterViewController, when user open your app, if he not logged in, he will redirect to Login page (by push(?) navigation) ?

Comment: Yes, correct! I did make it the root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your LoginController (or what name) add this line in `viewDidLoad`:

`self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;`

it will stop default pan gesture for popup. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have usually worked with this issue is to have another viewController that handles the login which is not part of the main app navigation.

The login controller can then do whatever it needs to login and do something like this after user is authenticated:

```
-(void) loginDidComplete {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kLoginKey];
    AppDelegate *appDelegateTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegateTemp.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                                           bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                                                 instantiateInitialViewController];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UserDidLogin" object:nil userInfo:nil];

}
```

And in the app delegate's application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, we can check if user is logged in by doing this:

```
if ([User userAuthenticated] ) //if user is auth correctly, then we go to the main view
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                                bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                                      instantiateInitialViewController];
}
else //otherwise we show the login controller
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                                bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
}
```

added a screenshot to demonstrate the 2 viewcontrollers in storyboard

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry - not really sure how to go about implementing your suggestion. I just started and began learning with storyboards so would it be possible for you to show an image example of how your storyboard would be laid out? I'm using Parse as the login authenticator and when I first launch the MasterViewController it checks for login authentication there. If not logged in then push to Login screen.

Comment: I added a screenshot - so basically the way I do it my "MasterViewController" will just do what the app is supposed to do. The login viewcontroller will take care of the login. Then you just change the 2 things as needed.

Comment: Or i guess another way is to have that login screen to be presented modally from your MasterViewController is the user is not logged in. Then it has to be dismissed before the user can see the view below it. Might be easier.